# Disable/Bypass JavaScript Client Side Validation

Tags: validation

Is there a way to entirely disable client side validation of list forms? Specifically the date field validation which occurs before the form is ever submitted.

I have tried PreSaveAction() but not sure how to actually bypass the validations.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to bypass the client side validations ? The data entered could be corrupted and would lead to inconsistant list data...

Answer (score 1):

You could off-course override the Javascript functions which handle the client side validations. Another solution would be to disable Javascript.

I don't think you should do either one of them though. Validation is there for a reason. Perhaps changing the validation logic on a form (or creating your own) is a better solution here.

Comment: It is a custom form I am working on. Certainly do not want to disable javascript. Which functions would need to be overridden? Basically just looking for how to disable required field validation on date/time fields. Other solution would be to validate EVERYTHING on the client side, but I don't know where to start there either.

Answer (score 0):

Move all your validation logic to PreSaveAction() and then check the condition on which you want to skip the validation and return true from the method.

[Nilesh](http://nileshmandekar.blogspot.in/)